# What to do with out of Date Answers

Tags: support

What do you do when a post has a question that you would like an answer to but the answer is out of date. Like [This One](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/182/is-it-possible-to-mine-bitcoins). Do you ask a similar question and risk having it closed or what do you do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Worth a read:

- [How do we encourage edits to obsolete/out of date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/284388)
- [How to deal with obsolete answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11705/284388)

---

The linked question is from 2012 and it makes no mention of the type and model of the Pi neither in the body nor using tags. However based on its data we could read the question being focused on the early models only. A new question for the Pi 2 or 3 would therefore (by the book) not be a dupe. Unfortunately the question focuses on the GPU and the GPU stayed the same for all Pi's. So in all honesty a new question should be closed as a dupe.

How to proceed from here?

**You would like to improve an answer**

[How do we encourage edits to obsolete/out of date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/284388) has it covered:

> - Comment to the OP suggesting that their answer is out-of date and needs to be updated
> - Post a new answer with the updated information
> - Edit or suggest an edit (if you don’t have privileges) to correct the answer

The first approach would be the best in an ideal world but since you cannot force the author of an existing answer to follow your hint (if they're still active that is) there is no guarantee it'll really work out.

Editing to update is another good idea... again with a catch. While the [helpcenter](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/editing) suggests that editing is supposed (emphasis mine):

> To correct minor mistakes or **add updates as the post ages**

those edits go through the review queue where they can be rejected with a reason along this line:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

I bet most substantial edits get rejected. So both commenting and editing may fail to improve the answer.

In a case like this I'd say that giving the OP a comment to suggest the need of an update **and** providing an own new answer is the way to go. If the new answer is comprehensive and up-to-date it will eventually collect enough upvotes to move up the list to be visible. I understand that this is sort of a problem on small sites where new posts usually collect two to five upvotes tops.

**You are interested in an updated answer but cannot provide one yourself**

If we agree that a new question should not be asked as it would be a dupe to the old one the only way besides commenting on existing answers is to encourage new answers to be posted. This requires to increase the visibility of the old question and the main tool to achieve this is placing a [bounty](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) on it:

> The bountied question will appear with a special indicator in all question lists, and it will also be visible on the homepage Featured tab for 7 days. Part of what you’re “paying for” with the bounty is to get additional attention for your question, over and beyond what a normal question gets. In that regard, a bounty does not guarantee a response, and reputation refunds are not available if no answers are received as a result of the bounty.

Talking about the topic on meta and in our chat room might also add to visibility a little (just a little, don't expect too much of it).

Comment: I [submitted an edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/61042) to correct the obsolete content of the post, and I think as long as you avoid adding an unreasonable amount of content that could conflict with the OP, doing that should be OK. I'm personally in favour of just editing unless there's a substantial amount to change, because, as you say, it's unlikely the votes will ever bring a new answer near the old ones (and it definitely won't if the obsolete answer is accepted).

Comment: @Aurora0001, that's a way to go. Here, have a hat!

Comment: An edit to at least note that the information is specific to hardware or an older OS release is useful, even if a full update is impractical.